# Drifting mouse cursor

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I have a Mac Book Retrina Pro. 
My mouse seems to drift to the right of screen all by itself. It doesn't matter if I am using the track pad, a bluetooth mouse or a USB external mouse (or no mouse at all).

It makes it very hard to scroll using the scroll bar arrows, because the mouse drifts while clicking.

How can I fix this?

I have searched on Google, but all the threads are from 2011. The consensus was then it was a software issue, but of course the OS is different now (I am using 10.11.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try disabling the Trackpad? One of my colleagues had this exact problem, and found out that it's actually an issue with the trackpad.

Comment: How do you disable it? There isn't an option in system preferences.

Comment: Follow this link : http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/disable-macbook-trackpad/